# full complex json object $http.post to node.js fails

Tags: node.js, angularjs, parsing

I  have this angularJs update query :

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/updateClub?club='+club)
```

Node.JS is able to see something but  can't update , this is the node jsconsole :

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
(node:3756) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead app.js:118:20
{ club: '[object Object]' }
undefined
```

This is my node.js code :

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

    // create application/json parser
    const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()



    app.post('/updateClub', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

            console.log(req.query);
            console.log(req.query.categorie); //Fails

            var myClub = req.query;

            MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
                var db = client.db('myDb');
                db.collection('clubs').updateOne({"_id":myClub._id},{$set:myClub}); 
            });

        })
```

This is my club object, please notice, there is an array included inside, as well as an object (there is also a >prototype< part, i dont know how to remove it):

```
Object { _id: "5d07e982a7d75a67d6383d6b", nom: "Angers Sp", identifiant: 4, date_creation: Date 1919-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, categorie: "professionel", structure: "Ligue 1", affectations: [], img: "data:image/png;base64,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…", adresse: {…}, ville: "Angers", … }
```

I also get this error message in firefox , but node.js seems to get the data anyway when it's parameters :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/updateClub?club=[object%20Object]. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me,thank you.
Others node.js queries are working with only parameters, not with a full object .

My clubs collection is working well and contains 25 clubs already

**EDIT 1:**
Changed my http query to :

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/updateClub',{data:$.param(club)})
```

And now , node.js req.body seems to get the object (document) :

```
{ data:
   '_id=5d07e982a7d75a67d6383d6b&nom=Angers+Sporting+Club+de+l\'Ouest+(SCO+Angers)&identifiant=4&date_creation=Wed+Jan+01+1919+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0000+(Central+European+Standard+Time)&categorie=professionel&structure=Ligue+1&img=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAYAAAAILCAYAAADhWEs5AAAABmJLR0QA%2FwD%2FAP%2BgvaeTAAAgAElEQVR4nOydd3hURffHv2mb3nsICQkhNNEAoQVBBfnRpFhAioIgwouAovQirwoiSEelKaBIF0SkCUhRREpCkRICoaU3kuym9%2Fn9sWTfBLbembt3s5nP88yT7O6dmXPn7s6ZOXPmDMDhcDgcDofD4XA4HA6Hw%2BFwOBwOh8PhcDgcs8FCagE49RoXAE4AnB%2F%2Fda%2Fxv%2FPjZAfA3oC%2FT5ZvVeO1BQA3HTKVASjU8FkBgPLH%2F8sBEACVAPIev1cCoLhGGfmP38t%2FnLfk8bWFj%2F9XPP5f%2FjiV6JCNw2EKVwAcWuwAeALwqPHXA4DXE%2B9V%2F3WFsoPX1RHXR4rxP2UgB5Cr5nUWgEePU%2Frj10VSCMup%2B3AFwFGHDIAPAH8Avo%2F%2FD3j81xeAX43PXSWSkfM%2FivA%2FhfAI%2F1MSKY%2FfSwKQ%2BjjxWQZHBVcA9Q8ZlB13QwBBAAIfpyAADR7%2F7
```

There is no cors warning any more

So this my last node.js code, now :

```
app.post('/updateClub', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body); // Can see the object in the console !

    var myClub = req.body;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
        var db = client.db('myDb');
        db.collection('clubs').updateOne({"_id":myClub._id},{$set:myClub}); // Fails
    });

})
```

It still doesnt update the object on mongodb

**EDIT 2:**

thank you George, Changed my front end query to this :

```
  $http.post('http://localhost:3000/updateClub',club)
```

And now, this is what the node console is displaying, a well formed object (sorry can't show all, there are annoying base64 pics) :

```
{ _id: '5d07e982a7d75a67d6383d6b',
  nom: 'Angers Sporting Club',
  identifiant: 4,
  date_creation: '1919-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  categorie: 'professionel',
  structure: 'Ligue 1',
  affectations: [],
  img: ...
```

This is my latest node.js code :

```
app.post('/updateClub', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body); // Can see the well formed object in the console !

    var myClub = req.body;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
        var db = client.db('myDb');
        db.collection('clubs').updateOne({"_id":myClub._id},{$set:myClub}); // There must be a mispelling, i need to replace the whole object (document)
    });

})
```

**EDIT 3 : a try With replaceOne()**

```
app.post('/updateClub', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body); // Can see the object in the console !

    var myClub = req.body;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
      if (err) throw err;       
     var db = client.db('myDb');
        db.collection('clubs').replaceOne({"_id":myClub._id},myClub); // Fails silently
    });

    })
```

note :tried plenty of things, insert() are working but not replaceOne() !

**EDIT 4**

Replaced my node.js by this :

```
try {
    db.collection('clubs').replaceOne({_id:"5d07e982a7d75a67d6383d6b"},myClub)
} catch (e){
   print(e);
}
```

This is still not updating ! Could it be because the "myClub" document is too big ? console.log(myClub._id) is working , but replaceOne() fails silently !

console.log(typeof(myClub)) gives object, so it should be ok !

**EDIT 6 :** The ANGULARJS object is not the same than the node.js received one !

I've found the error,The Node.js Parsed JSON contains [Object] instead of the nested objects data:

```
adresse:
   { address_components:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     adr_address:
```

How can i get rid of this and get the real objects datas ? (the AngularJs sentobject contains allof the "object"data,then node.js is replacing it by [object] , why,please help ?

**EDIT 7 :**
Changed my front end to this :

```
 $http.post('http://localhost:3000/updateClub',club, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
```

Changed my node.js code to this :

```
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    inflate: true,
    strict:false
}));
```

**My nested JSON  objects still aren't parsed**, instead, there is [object]

I've tried all of the options :https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser?_ga=1.163627447.940445150.1418712389#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

What should i do to get the content  of my nested objects ??

**Edit 8**

I've got an answer from the officialstaff :

**By default, the Node.js console.log only shows to a depth of 2.:**

so

console.dir(req.body, { depth: Infinity }) is showing correctly the entire JSON document.

So i really don't know why the replaceOne()  isn't working, i'm bloqued,I have no explanation.

**EDIT 9 : SEMI SOLVED**

I ended  up with this code, but i dont think it's the best thing to do, ive  added a second identifier who was coming from my old bdd, so i use it as a filter, and delete the mongoDb generated _id who was generating an error, then the replace is working:

```
  app.post('/updateClub', function (req, res) {


        myClub = req.body;

        delete myClub._id;

        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {


            if (err) throw err;
            var db = client.db('myDb');

            try {
            db.collection('clubs').replaceOne({"identifiant":myClub.identifiant},myClub)
            } catch (e){
               print(e);
            }
        })
    })
```

Edit: tried to remove the quotes from myClub._id and tried the first code provided with no luck
myClub._id = myClub._id.replace(/["']/g, "");

This is myClub._id : 5d07e982a7d75a67d6383d6c , looks nice

**FINAL :**

Ok i've found an explanation there :

https://litote.org/kmongo/dokka/kmongo/org.litote.kmongo/com.mongodb.client.-mongo-collection/replace-one-with-filter.html

Well, I need to use _id to be able to replace one, it 's more convenient.

Comment: Just post the data normally: `$http.post(url, club)`.

Comment: What does it fail with? Btw, please edit your question a bit and just leave the latest version of code - it's not really well readable.

Comment: Yes thank you George,I see a well formed document inside the node.js console now with your code , but it still doesnt seem to  update, i bet my updating code part is wrong